# Line and Plane Intersection

Tags: vectors

Line $L$ has equation:

> $ r = 5i - 3j - k + α (i - 2j + k)$

Plane $P $ has equation:

> $ (r - I - 2j) • (3i + j + k) = 0$

The line and Plane intersect at point A. Find the position vector of A.

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you must have had some ideas and attempts before you decided it was worth the effort to sign up on this site.

Comment: I mean I am kind of unfamiliar with the format of equation of the plane. Normally it is in the form of r.n = n.a

Comment: So what's stopping you from rearranging it? We have $(r-i-2j)\cdot (3i+j+k) = r\cdot (3i+j+k) - (i + 2j)\cdot(3i + j + k)$. Now just move one part over to the other side of the equality sign, and you have the form you're used to.

Comment: Understandable. Thank you for that. I was confused about the r.